# How to correctly extend an ANTLR4 grammar?

Tags: antlr4

I have a requirement where I want to extend an existing grammar A with additions defined in grammar B to produce a grammar C.

I have already tried importing grammar A in B, but that selects only certain things defined in grammar A. My guess is that the unused content of A in B is skipped while generating classes. This makes sense as the requirement is not to inherit but intermix/ merge/ combine the two grammars.

Just for understanding (the original grammar is huge), an example:

**File : A.g4:**

```
grammar A;

keywords
    : X
    | Y
    | Z
    ;

X: 'X';
Y: 'Y';
Z: 'Z';
```

**File : B.g4:**

```
grammar B;

keywords
    : A
    | B
    | C
    ;

A: 'A';
B: 'B';
C: 'C';
```

**File : C.g4:**

```
grammar C;

keywords
    : X
    | Y
    | Z
    | A
    | B
    | C
    ;

X: 'X';
Y: 'Y';
Z: 'Z';
A: 'A';
B: 'B';
C: 'C';
```

**Note:** I do not have the option to manipulate the grammar A directly, but I want to retain all the functionality in grammar A along with the additional rules/ keywords etc. defined in grammar B as shown above.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: All your grammars miss an import statement. Please add them yet.

Answer (score 0):

Grammar import might not work as you expect it to work. Rules in the importing grammar take precedence over same named rules in the imported grammar. Thus you cannot override an existing rule in your main grammar. See also the [description in the ANTLR4 repo](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/grammars.md#grammar-imports):

> Think of import as more like a smart include statement (which does not include rules that are already defined).

However, it should be possible to override a rule in a second import grammar. In your case, you would not define the `keywords` in your main grammar (I assume this is `C`). Import the grammars `A` and `B`in reverse order if you want `B`´s `keywords` rule to take precedence over the one in `A`.

```
import B, A;
```

This is also demonstrated in the image from this Markdown file:

[image]

The rule `r` from grammar `G2` is ignored, since it is imported last, so `G3` kinda "overrides" it.

Comment: mike, I understand how imports work but this is related to merging two composite grammars to create a third grammar

Comment: Then my answer should help you.

Comment: "Thus you cannot [overwrite] an existing rule in your main grammar" is a bit confusing.  Do you mean that B cannot modify a rule in C? Doesn't sound like the OP is trying to do that, but instead having B modify a rule from A.

Comment: The docs state import is like an include operation, which ignores rules that already exist. This should make clear that you cannot override a rule in your importing grammar. However, if your importing grammar imports 2 other grammars and they contain both a rule that doesn't exist in the importing grammar, this rule **will** be imported there. Which of the two depends on the order of the imported grammars. The grammar which contains the final rule should be imported first (because then the second import can no longer override that rule). This is exactly what the image shows.